# Swift - Pointer to a Pointer

Tags: swift

I'm trying to figure out how to create a pointer to a pointer in Swift. Now, I know we don't exactly have pointers in Swift, but here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
var foo = objA() //foo is variable referencing an instance of objA
var bar = foo    //bar is a second variable referencing the instance above

foo = objA()     //foo is now a reference to a new instance of objA, but bar
                 //is still a reference to the old instance
```

I would like to have `bar` be a reference to the `foo` variable instead of it being a reference to the `foo` object. That way, if `foo` becomes a reference to a different object, `bar` goes along for the ride.

Comment: Why do you need pointers at all?

Comment: It's a solution to a problem I will most likely solve another way, but I was really curious as to how it could be done.

Comment: How about asking us about _that actual problem_? Maybe we can help you think of a good way to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I know other ways to solve the problem, I am just interested in how it could be solved this particular way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of having a secondary reference to a variable would be a **computed** variable:

```
class C {}

var a = C()
var b: C { return a }  // b is a computed variable, returning the current value of a

b === a  // true
a = C()
b === a  // true, whereas "var b = a" would have made this false
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine, didn't even think about computed properties; +1

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you want:

```
class O {
    let n: Int
    init(n: Int) { self.n = n }
}

var foo = O(n: 1)
var bar = withUnsafePointer(&foo) {$0}
print(bar.pointee.n) // Prints 1

foo = O(n: 2)
print(bar.pointee.n) // Prints 2
```

(Replace `pointee` with `memory` for Swift < 3.0)

I really don't know why you'd want that though.

Comment: This is extremely unsafe, as it allows to reference the object via `bar` even after it has been deallocated. The pointer passed to the closure of withUnsafePointer should never be used outside the context of that closure.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `UnsafeMutablePointer`. See an example below:

```
let string = UnsafeMutablePointer<String>.alloc(1)
string.initialize("Hello Swift")

print(string.memory)

let next = string
next.memory = "Bye Bye Swift"

print(string.memory) // prints "Bye Bye Swift"
```

But it smells a little and It will be better to avoid using technique like this.